# Mysql Copy a serialised table from one database to another

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization

I hope someone can help here. I have Wordpress Quform plugin on my site. One of the forms has got corrupted. When i check the tables in the database I can see that the form is missing nearly all of its data.

I have a two backups of the database on the server and also off site backups. I access mysql via PHPMyadmin

Is there a way in PHPMyadmin or any other way, where i can copy the table from one of the backups on or off the server and replace the broken table without losing searlisation?

Hope that makes sense :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have .sql backup file of database then use that file and run it in mysql command line it will create database

Then you will be able to copy data from table of backedup db to new/other db with code as shown below

In Code Below db2 is second db (created from .sql backup file ) and db1 is new db to which we need to copy data to .

```
CREATE TABLE db1.tblcoupon
AS
SELECT * FROM db2.tblcoupon
```

Comment: I have gone in via command line and changed directory to where the databases are. I have run the commands but it is not creating the table :(

Comment: @PalmIntSrv I have upated the command in my answer and recently tested it in mysql and it worked let me know if it works on your side